# mdadm rotate hot spare

Tags: scripting, cron, raid, mdadm

It can be a good idea to have a hot spare in some RAID systems.  It can be a bad idea for the hot spare to sit idle for months/years, potentially hiding a defect, until an active drive fails and activating the hot spare reveals the defect.

What are best practices with mdadm for automatically (say monthly, although that feels a tad frequent for some large arrays) rotating which disk is the hot spare among the set of disks?  Preferably while always in the condition that a "failed rotate" merely marks the hot spare bad and keeps the array running?

(Bonus point: anyone have a cron/script for doing this, rotating the "hot spare" cyclically through the disks, fairly evenly distributing the vacation time among the disks?

(Bonus bonus point: the script has some way for a user to specify a (just barely SMART-twitchy) drive to be the next hot spare, to facilitate its replacement without extra array stress.))

Comment: "Bonus" point: think about RAID1+spare, you mark disk1 as "bad", start rebuild mirror and disk2 fail.... And IMHO there is no practice to "rotate" spare disk(s)

Comment: @RomeoNinov : Yes.  Marking disk1 as bad violates "always in the condition that a "failed rotate" merely marks the hot spare bad and keeps the array running".  This is what `--replace` is for.

Comment: RAID 1 + spare does not make sense, just use 3-way RAID 1 then. Same for RAID 5 + spare, just use RAID 6. More redundancy >> spare. Not sure what's the point of spare rotation, just do SMART selftest on all drives. (Opinionated, up to you how you want to manage things.)